# Understanding retain count with the blocks accessing self inside it.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I have a basic understanding of weak reference with the blocks. The problem I am facing is,

Whenever I access **self** inside the block, the retain count of self gets increased by **2**, where as when I access self inside the default block(example UIViewAnimation) the retain count for self gets increased by 1.

Just wanted to understand why it is getting increased by 2.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The block will want to retain 'captured' iVars (like self) to ensure the reference remains valid ... ie that `self` does not deallocate before it executes. You will find good info on this here (different treatment for MRC and ARC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227982/using-block-and-weak

Comment: Also to better understand weak read https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thanks for sharing the link. I was just checking the behavior of the block for that specific case, where it goes to 2.

Comment: @David thanks for sharing the links. I was just checking the behavior of the block for that specific case, where it goes to 2.

Comment: @jrturton the link you have shared made me think over the retain count.

Comment: When ARC is running, looking at retain counts is absolutely pointless. It will do nothing more than confuse you. There are very few conclusions that you can draw from any retain counts, and no valid conclusions at all when ARC is involved.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: Blocks only "capture" local variables. Never ivars.

Answer (score 1):

According to Clang source code for generating code of Objective-C blocks.

- [CGBlocks.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/1c4187aa7bfb64ed4746886df047722e1dc6a37e/lib/CodeGen/CGBlocks.cpp)
- [CGDecl.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/1c4187aa7bfb64ed4746886df047722e1dc6a37e/lib/CodeGen/CGDecl.cpp)
- [CGObjC.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/1c4187aa7bfb64ed4746886df047722e1dc6a37e/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp)

Objective-C blocks literal is generated by `EmitBlockLiteral` function.

```
llvm::Value *CodeGenFunction::EmitBlockLiteral(const CGBlockInfo &blockInfo) {
```

[LLVM document](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#high-level) explains deeply what is Block literal. Anyway this function generates a block descriptor and a copy helper function of the specified block. The copy helper function is for capturing auto variables and `self`.

```
buildBlockDescriptor -> buildCopyHelper -> GenerateCopyHelperFunction
```

In `GenerateCopyHelperFunction` function, Clang emits `objc_storeStrong` for each Objective-C object auto variable that will be captured by the block.

```
for (const auto &CI : blockDecl->captures()) {
    ...
    EmitARCStoreStrongCall(...
```

So, this line would count up the retain count of `self` (1 -> 2).

After that, `EmitBlockLiteral` function emits `objc_retain` for each Objective-C object auto variable that will be captured by the block, as well.

```
// Next, captured variables.
for (const auto &CI : blockDecl->captures()) {
    ...
    EmitExprAsInit -> EmitScalarInit -> EmitARCRetain
```

Therefore this line would count up the retain count of `self` too (2 -> 3).

I don't know the exact reason. But apparently, there is some reason to retain Objective-C object before capturing object by the block copy helper function.

Answer (score -1):

Using self inside a block, usually creates a cycle which could be the reason why it gets increased by 2. To fix this, you should try using a weak self. Check this question out

[capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556605/capturing-self-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a-retain-cycle)

Use something like this
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

Comment: Using `self` inside a block does not create a cycle. It creates a reference from the block to `self`. It only creates a cycle if you make a cycle -- if you keep a reference from `self` to the block. That is not what is happening here.