# Variable not changed by AFNetworking GET function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use an AFNetworking class to retrieve data from a database.  Long story short, the data received from the parameter `responseObject` is filled with items.  Here is my problem however.  I am trying to copy the results in `responseObject` into an `NSDictionary` called `results`.  I used the following code to get there:

```
__block NSDictionary *results;

[manager GET:@"http://daneolog.altervista.org/app/getData.php"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { results = responseObject;
     NSLog(@"Inside: %@", results); }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { NSLog(@"%@", error); }];

NSLog(@"Outside: %@", results);
```

I tried `NSLog`ing the `results` dictionary ***INSIDE*** the success braces, and everything is a-okay there.

I tried `NSLog`ing the `results` dictionary ***OUTSIDE*** the GET function, and it comes up as (null).

These are my results:

```
2015-11-12 14:34:34.875 TestApp[4864:258743] Outside: (null)
2015-11-12 14:34:35.242 TestApp[4864:258743] Inside: (
        {
        address = "Sample Address";
    }
)
```

Now notice the peculiar thing: the outside NSLog is being executed first.  I don't know why this is so.  Can anyone help me on this?  Thanks a bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Your code outside the success block is executing before the success block completes that is why `results` come up as `null`.  `results` is on the main thread, and you are not blocking (as is correct with an HTTP request).

You can pass a weak reference to an object, and have that updated.  Or if you absolutely need to wait for the result (login for instance) then you should do it on the main thread.

Here is an example of a weak object:

```
//results is an object created earlier

__weak NSDictionary *weakResults = results;

[manager GET:@"http://daneolog.altervista.org/app/getData.php"
     parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {     
             weakResults = responseObject;
             NSLog(@"Inside: %@", results); 
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {  
             NSLog(@"%@", error); 
     }];


//when the success block finishes the results object will be populated
```

If you wanted to block i.e. do it on the main thread you could use:

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

However, if the response doesn't come back, your app hangs.

Comment: Mmm... I knew something along those lines were happening.  How should I  "pass a weak reference to an object, and have that updated"?  I don't really know much Objective-C (which is why I'm using AFNetworking in the first place :))

Comment: Oook.  Here's a funny problem.  Whenever I try to access weakResults, it complains at me saying it has to have a __block type specifier. :'(

Comment: Here is some information on __block and __weak:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227982/using-block-and-weak

Comment: Umm... yeah.  So how would I do an AFNetworking GET function on the main thread?